# find with filter and callback

Tags: typescript, mongoose, jestjs, mocking

I can mock the version of find that goes

```
Model.find({'a': 'b'}).then(value => {
///whatever
}).catch(err => whatever.else());
```

In jest by going:

```
Educator.find = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({'hi': 'its me'});
```

And then when the call to find is made, the promise resolves as expected.  Model.find has another syntax that passes the callback in (rather than using a returned the promise), e.g.:

```
Model.find({'a': 'b'}, (err: any, value: IModel) => {
  if (err) {
    // whatever error handling
  }
  // whatever you want with the result
});
```

I tried

```
Model.find = jest.fn((conditions, callback) => {callback(null, {'oi': 'its a me'})})
```

But then I get an error "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Query<any, any, {}, IModel>'" - so it thinks I'm trying to mock the version of find defined like so:

```
    find<ResultDoc = HydratedDocument<T, TMethodsAndOverrides, TVirtuals>>(
      filter: FilterQuery<T>,
      projection?: ProjectionType<T> | null | undefined,
      options?: QueryOptions<T> | null | undefined,
      callback?: Callback<ResultDoc[]> | undefined
    ): QueryWithHelpers<Array<ResultDoc>, ResultDoc, TQueryHelpers, T>;
```

But really I want this one:

```
    find<ResultDoc = HydratedDocument<T, TMethodsAndOverrides, TVirtuals>>(
      filter: FilterQuery<T>,
      callback?: Callback<ResultDoc[]> | undefined
    ): QueryWithHelpers<Array<ResultDoc>, ResultDoc, TQueryHelpers, T>;
```

Hope what I'm asking makes sense. I'd like to know how to mock this properly.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

This worked as expected

```
    Model.find = jest.fn((conditions, callback) => {
      if (callback) callback(null, {'oi': 'its a me'});
      return new Query<any, any, {}, IModel>();
    });
```

I bet there is a cleaner way though -- would still love to know!

Comment: This is a good example of why you shouldn't mock what you don't own. So that your tests don't fail for the trivial refactor between the callback and promise APIs and to satisfy the needs of interfaces you don't care about, you're now having to implement both. Write a thin wrapper that you own, and mock that instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That makes more sense!